# Error "no py in the root" when I build python library with pyo3 in Rust

Tags: python, rust

### My Environments

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Rust 1.39.0-nightly
- Python 3.7.3

### What I want to do and the problems

I want to write a library for python. As my practice, I tried the code in document.

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Yudai Hayashi"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[lib]
name = "example"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "*"
features = ["extension-module"]
```

src/lib.rs

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro, specialization)]

extern crate pyo3;
use pyo3::{py, PyResult, Python, PyModule};

use pyo3::py::modinit as pymodinit;

// add bindings to the generated python module
// N.B: names: "librust2py" must be the name of the `.so` or `.pyd` file
/// This module is implemented in Rust.
#[pymodinit(rust2py)]
fn init_mod(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {

    #[pyfn(m, "sum_as_string")]
    // pyo3 aware function. All of our python interface could be declared in a separate module.
    // Note that the `#[pyfn()]` annotation automatically converts the arguments from
    // Python objects to Rust values; and the Rust return value back into a Python object.
    fn sum_as_string_py(_: Python, a:i64, b:i64) -> PyResult<String> {
       let out = sum_as_string(a, b);
       Ok(out)
    }

    Ok(())
}

// logic implemented as a normal Rust function
fn sum_as_string(a:i64, b:i64) -> String {
    format!("{}", a + b).to_string()
}
```

When I build this program, I got some errors.

```sh
error[E0432]: unresolved import `pyo3::py`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:12
  |
4 | use pyo3::{py, PyResult, Python, PyModule};
  |            ^^
  |            |
  |            no `py` in the root
  |            help: a similar name exists in the module: `Py`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `pyo3::py`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:11
  |
6 | use pyo3::py::modinit as pymodinit;
  |           ^^ could not find `py` in `pyo3`

error: cannot determine resolution for the attribute macro `pymodinit`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:3
   |
11 | #[pymodinit(rust2py)]
   |   ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports

error: cannot find attribute macro `pyfn` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:14:7
   |
14 |     #[pyfn(m, "sum_as_string")]
   |       ^^^^

error: aborting due to 4 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: Could not compile `example`.
```

This error message says that there is no "py" in pyo3 module. I looked for this error message, but I cannot find similar errors.

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [no `mod` called `py`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.8.0/pyo3/) in the latest version of `pyo3`. You've landed on documentation or examples related to an old version of the library. The last version that had this `mod` was 0.2.7.

If you have no interest other than running the code, set the version you require of `pyo3` in your `Cargo.toml` dependencies to `0.2.7` and it should compile out of the box (a cursory glance confirms that all symbols seem to exist in that version).

If you want to actually investigate the newer version, [the new documentation](https://pyo3.rs/v0.8.0/module.html) has up to date examples.

Comment: Thank you! I tried newer version and succeeded in execution!